# How Can i Insert Value in Mysql if it is Unknown?

Tags: mysql, database

Hello Friend I need Help About Mysql. My Database Look Like This 
Table name = users

Rows

```
id = "7" | YourLastIP = ""
```

MY Query is:

```
UPDATE users SET `YourLastIP` = `XX.XX.XX.XX` WHERE `id` = `7`
```

I want to insert but it also wont work for me please guide me

```
 INSERT INTO Users `YourLastIP` = (`XX.XX.XX.XX`) WHERE `id` = `7`
```

Please Help me How to Insert A value if table value not known.

Comment: So do you want to insert or update? Which one? For the `update` you have to put the value `XX.XX.XX.XX` in `''` like this: `UPDATE users SET YourLastIP = 'XX.XX.XX.XX' WHERE id = 7`

Answer (score 1):

You are using backticks which means in MySQL that you're meaning a column name, not text. Use single quotes `'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, the problem is that you have wrap the value with backtick, which is suppose to be single quote since it is a string literal.

```
UPDATE users SET `YourLastIP` = 'XX.XX.XX.XX' WHERE `id` = '7'
```

Second, use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` if you want to `UPDATE` existing *ID* or otherwise `INSERT` if it does not exist.

```
INSERT INTO users(ID, YourLastIP)
VALUES (7, 'ip_here')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE YourLastIP = 'ip_here'
```

- [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with [`SQL Injection`](http://bobby-tables.com/) if the value(*s*)  of the variables came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using `PreparedStatements` you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Make the column NULLABLE in definition

Then,

```
CREATE TABLE PRO(ID INT, YOURLASTIP VARCHAR(15));
INSERT INTO PRO values(4, "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
```